# Error Converting Pandas Dataframe to float with comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I got a Dataframe with at least 2-3 columns with numbers running from 1 to 3000,
and the numbers have comma. I need to convert the numbers to float or int in all the relevant columns.this is an example for my Dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv('exampleData.csv')
data.head(10)
 Out[179]:
 Rank     Total
  1         2
  20        40
  1,200    1,400
  NaN       NaN
```

as you can see from the example, my Dataframe consists of numbers, numbers with comma and some NaNs.I've read several posts here about converting to float or int, but I always get error messages such as: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'.
my approach is as follows for several columns:

```
cols = ['Rank', 'Total']
data[cols] = data[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.astype(str)
                                               .str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: Just tried to run your code and it works perfectly here.

Comment: what is the `dtype` of each column?

Comment: dtype is object. maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John's solution won't work for numbers with multiple commas, like 1,384,496.

A more scalable solution would be to just do

`data = data.replace({",":""}, regex=True)`

Then convert the strings to numeric.

Comment: I did this part, but when I try to change to numeric, I still get the error message. I checked the columns and they are of type 'Object'

Answer (score 2):

Use the argument `thousands`.

```
pd.read_csv('exampleData.csv', thousands=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas read_csv() takes many arguments which allow you to control how fields are converted.  From [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
decimal : str, default ‘.’
    Character to recognize as decimal point (e.g. use ‘,’ for European data).
```

So, here's a crazy idea: convert the numerical fields using the keyword argument, "decimal = ',' ".  Then, multiply the numerical fields by 1000.